# DD4T configuration

Tags: dd4t

We are planning to move to using [DD4T](https://code.google.com/p/dynamic-delivery-4-tridion/) for a new website. Currently the cd_deployer is in Linux. We have the following questions:

1. Do we need to switch cd_deployer to Windows server while using DD4T?
2. I am a novice to DD4T, but have gone through the reference documentation. However I could not find how the DD4T application gets the Broker database connection details to the DD4T MVC Application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Windows NT? o_O

Answer (score 9):

1. No, DD4T doesn't care about your deployer, you can use whatever setup you like. DD4T consumes data through the normal Content Delivery APIs.
2. As mentioned in point 1, DD4T uses the normal Content Delivery APIs, so in your web application you still have all of the JARs and config xml files associated with that (cd_storage_conf.xml), just like a 'traditional' application that uses Content Delivery.

Answer (score 7):

(Assuming you are planning on using the ASP.NET MVC framework from MS)

1. No, you don't need to switch to a Windows NT deployer server.
2. DD4T uses the OOTB Tridion .NET API to connect to the Broker. The connection details are stored in the cd_storage_conf.xml which should be in 
   bin\config (Or in the config directory of the `%TRIDION_HOME%` environment variable).

DD4T is all about the ASP.NET MVC framework. Make yourself familiar with it. DD4T just adds the layer to query the broker by URL and renders the 
correct view as managed in Tridion.

[self-promoting]Visit [this link](http://albertromkes.com/2011/12/13/getting-started-with-asp-net-mvc3-and-tridion/) for some 'getting started info' [/self-promoting]

If you have any follow up questions, don't hesitate to ask.